# table value function using entity framework‬

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity, user-defined-functions

I'm working with SQL trying to implement a Full-Text-Search. I noticed that there is no direct handling to Full-Text-Search in Linq.

I've read that I can use UDF that will return a table. I tried using that but EF doesn't recognize my functions, although I did read somewhere that the new version of EF (4.2) should support UDF.

I also tried implementing a Custom Function through SSDL but the problem was I couldn't keep filtering the query beyond the result line in linq, giving the error: `the result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once`.

Hope I was clear about my issue.

What do you think is the best approach I should use?

Comment: Why a UDF, and not just a stored procedure? Your error "*the result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once*" is usually fixed by putting the result in a `List` first. Did you try that?

Comment: putting the result set into a list might be expensive if the result set will have many rows (the table contains more than a milion records). Plus I still need to do more filtering on the result with linq and only then choose 10 rows to render. UDF returns a table which I can filter after with linq, and I think stored procedure doesn't return a table that you can manipulate with linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TVFs are not supported yet, it will come with .Net 4.5, but I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx) might help you. Als you might consider other ORM just to get Full Text Search working (Linq2Sql maybe, it supports TVF).

Comment: From what I understand Microsoft already released it's 5.0 beta version.  But it is still beta. And since I am working with linq2entities I don't want to switch all to linq2sql just because of FTS.

Comment: You don't need to switch all, just that table with FTS.